# Add xml layout file within an update to existing apk

Tags: android, xml, recompile

I'm developing an Android application (a game). Users can download the apk from Google Play. I want to add some more XML layouts and some images to the existing apk in an update. But XML layouts and other images are supposed to be stored in github.

How to add these XML layouts and images to the existing apk? Do I need to use a recompile mechanism using a third party library? What is the optimum method?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2481797?hl=en

http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

Hope these websites might help you. :)